# post an image on my profile tagging a friend facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've a facebook application and I'm using a Feed and Share Dialog popup to post an image on my personal profile. My goal is to tag a friend of mine (instead of posting it on his timeline, I can not change this behaviour for a customer request - considered less spammy).
So, the question is, is there a way to tag a friend in the post? According the API of Feed and Share Dialogs it's not possible, but how can I do that?
Here's the code.

```
var sIdPersonalProfile = [my personal id profile];
var sIdFriendProfile = [my friend id profile];

var hFacebookData = {
    method: 'feed',
    display : 'popup',
    name: 'NAME_APP',
    caption: 'CAPTION_APP',
    description: 'DESCRIPTION_APP',
    picture: 'URL_APP',
    to: sIdPersonalProfile
};

FB.ui(hFacebookData, callback);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already figured out how to `POST` the image to your personal profile. Then, to tag yourself or someone else is quite easy. You need to issue `POST` request to one of the following urls:

1. `https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID`
2. `https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID`

or, if you need to tag more than one user you need to pass an array of user ids...

'https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/tags?tags=[{"tag_uid":"1234"}, {"tag_uid":"12345"}]`

This operations will require the following permissions are passed in the `scope` parameter...

1. `user_photos`
2. `publish_stream`

You can also specify some extra parameters such as the coordinates of the location of the tag in the image and a tag caption. For more info, check out the [Facebook Developer Photo API to publish tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo#tags)

Comment: is it even possible to tag a friend if instead of posting an image, i post a text?

Comment: Where does it say that?